# What are good sources for iPhone 4/iPad wallpapers?

Tags: iphone, ipad

There are plenty of sites out there that compile wallpapers, but most have a very low signal:noise ratio. I don't want to deal with so much 'rough' to find a couple 'diamonds'. Are there places that have a generally high level of quality?

Comment: I can't mark this as "Community Wiki" although I believe it should be one.

Comment: flag this for moderator attention so they can mark it as community wiki

Comment: Done and done. Now a community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mantia](http://mantia.me/wallpaper/) (who now works for Apple) has a nice selection of geeky iPhone/iPad wallpapers. Some of his stuff is featured at the [Iconfactory](http://iconfactory.com/freeware/desktop?page=1), along with some other wallpapers by Dave Brasgalla, Gedeon Maheux and others.